# Not able to map to values of the object inside an array fetched from mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

When I am getting the values in postman, the values are null, and when I am consoling the titleArr, it is saying that the value of obj.title is undefined

**the obj.title is undefined**

```
  router.get("/userID/:userId/title/", verify, async (req, res) => {
  const userIdParam = Number(req.params.userId);
  const postsObj = await PostsModel.find({ userId: userIdParam });
  const titleArr = postsObj.map((obj) => obj.title);
  res.send(titleArr);
});
```

Comment: Try consoling postsObj (this will give some hints on whether the data returned is indeed expected). If the result is not the expected one, try consoling the req object itself, could be the case where params value isn't correct?

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your issue.

```js
  router.get("/userID/:userId/title/", verify, async (req, res) => {
  const userIdParam = Number(req.params.userId);
  const postsObj = await PostsModel.find({ userId: userIdParam });
  const titleArr = postsObj.map((obj) => obj._doc.title); // <= Add _doc here
  res.send(titleArr);
});
```

**Explain:** `find` method return array of `model object`, which contains data in `_doc` field.